# Looking for Sound/Voice advice for an Audio Clip I'm editing in Pro Tools!

Tags: audio-recording, audio, voice-over, audio-restoration, production-audio

Im new to audio production and I am creating a cartoon for youtube.  I was wondering if anyone could listen to this audio clip and tell me why it doesnt sound very good.  Then let me know what I can do in Pro Tools to fix the problem.  I can tell it doesnt sound that good but I cant figure out whats wrong with it.  If anyone is willing to help, you could write your email and Ill email it to you.

Thanks!

Comment: 2 things.First,  xan you put a question as your title an second can you put a link so people can listen to your audio clip ? Best :)